# Is this definition of an ideal wrong? (Artin's Algebra, 2nd Edition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

[image: Artin2]

I think it is a typo because the condition "$I$ is closed under addition" cannot guarantee that $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$.

Thanks.

Comment: He likely assumes $1 \in R$, so now $I$ contains all negatives (second bullet), and $I$ is also nonempty, so....

Comment: @Randall Oh, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artin assumes that all rings are **unital**. Given that, the second criterion ensures that $(R,+)$ is closed under additive inverses since we always have $-a=(-1)a$.

In a non-unital ring of course this can fail: consider for example the even integers other than $-2$ as a subset of the non-unital ring $2\mathbb{Z}$. So if you're considering non-unital rings, you do indeed need the stronger definition.

Comment: Sometimes the term "rng" is used to refer to non-unital rings ("ring without **i**dentity"), but this seems to be pretty rare.

Comment: In the gaming community, "rng" has another meaning altogether: the "random number generator", or sometimes the "random number god".

Comment: @NoahSchweber Knowing that Artin requires a "1" for a ring, I didn't realize that this would simplify the definition. Thank you so much for the answer and comment!